# Where am I failing?

Tags: java, eclipse

first of all ty for reading this. Second im having a struggle in putting this to work, this should ask for the name address phone etc but this gives me an error in the "Conta"...

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NumberFormatException,
            IOException {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int NumeroClientes = 0;
        Banco banco = new Banco();
        Cliente[] c = banco.getclientes();
        while (true) {

            System.out.println("Qual é a tua escolha?");
            System.out.println("1: Adicionar Cliente");
            System.out.println("2: Depositar Dinheiro");
            System.out.println("3: Levantar Dinheiro");
            System.out.println("4: Verificar Saldo Bancario");
            System.out.println("5: Sair");

            int choice = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Criação de uma nova Conta-Cliente");
                System.out.println("Insira o seu nome: ");
                String Nome = bufferedReader.readLine();// NAME
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente(Nome, Conta);
                System.out.println("Insira a sua morada: ");
                String Morada = bufferedReader.readLine();// ADDRESS

                System.out.println("Insira o seu numero de telefone: ");
                // TELEPHONE
                System.out.println("Insira o seu CC: ");
                // SOCIALCARD
                System.out.println("Insira o seu Contribuinte: ");
                // FINCARD

                System.out.println("O seu saldo inicial é: 0.0");

                break;
            case 2:

                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                System.exit(0); // EXIT
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }}
```

if u guys want i can put the other classes ...

costumer class:

```
public class Cliente {
private String Nome;
private String Morada;
private int Telefone;
private int CC;
private int Contribuinte;
private Conta Conta;

Cliente(String n, Conta a) {
    Nome = n;
    Conta = a;
}

public void mostrar() {

    System.out.println("Nome: " + Nome + ", Numero de conta: " + Conta.getNumeroConta()+", Saldo Bancario: "+Conta.getSaldo());

}

public String getName() {
    return Nome;

}

public String getMorada() {
    return Morada;

}

public int getTelefone() {

    return Telefone;

}

public int getCC() {

    return CC;

}

public int getContribuinte() {

    return Contribuinte;

}

public Conta getConta() {
    return Conta;
}}
```

Conta class:

```
public class Conta {

private double Saldo = 0.0;
private String NumeroConta;
private boolean PrimeiraVez = true;

public Conta(String num) {
    NumeroConta = num;
}

public Conta(double sal, String num) {
    if (Saldo == 0) {
        sal = Saldo;

    } else {

        sal = 0;

    }

    NumeroConta = num;
}

public void crédito(double Quanto) {

    if (Quanto > 0) {
        Saldo = Saldo + Quanto;
        System.out.println(Quanto + "foi depositado com sucesso."
                + "O seu saldo bancario é " + Saldo);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Por favor meta quantias positivas!");
    }

}

public void débito(double Quanto) {
    if (Quanto >= 0) {
        if (PrimeiraVez == true) {
            double tempSaldo = Saldo;
            tempSaldo = tempSaldo - Quanto;
            if (tempSaldo >= 0) {
                Saldo = Saldo - Quanto;
            }

            else {
                System.err.println("Fundos insuficientes! " + Quanto);
            }
            PrimeiraVez = false;

        }
    } else {
        System.err.println("Por favor não metas valores negativos!");

    }
}

public double getSaldo() {

    return Saldo;

}

public String getNumeroConta() {
    return NumeroConta;
}}
```

Comment: Where are you defining the variable `Conta`?

Comment: If you're receiving an error **post it**. Don't make us sit here and guess/speculate as to what it might be.

Comment: the error says "Conta cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Your problem is you're referencing a private variable in a different class by name. Obviously it won't resolve. You're also referring to it without a reference of that class, even if it were public that wouldn't work. Read up on Java access modifiers and how they work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conta is not initialized : try

```
String Nome = bufferedReader.readLine();// NAME
Cliente cliente = new Cliente(Nome, new Conta("The account number"));
```

Comment: This is not the problem @DemonProgrammer is seeing at all.

Comment: @Kon i don't understand what you want to say.

Comment: @Kon I already posted the class can u tell me why doesnt work properly?